# Entity Framework Edit/Delete Record Works on Local & Azure Staging Slot - Error In Production

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure-web-app-service

I have a Web App running in Azure. I set up Entity Framework to access my database. The Edit and Delete views work on my local machine and when deployed to the Staging slot. When I push to the production slot I get an error. For some reason the Controller is not reading in the record ID, even though it is clearly being passed in the URL and is set up in RouteConfig.

UPDATE: 
Here's the request. 
https://teamweb.azurewebsites.net/JobTracking/Edit/41ba2cca-3e6c-4920-9f2f-92f656ab4374
I am receiving a 500 Error.

UPDATE 2:
Here's the Exception

> A claim of type
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier'
>   or
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider'
>   was not present on the provided ClaimsIdentity. To enable anti-forgery
>   token support with claims-based authentication, please verify that the
>   configured claims provider is providing both of these claims on the
>   ClaimsIdentity instances it generates. If the configured claims
>   provider instead uses a different claim type as a unique identifier,
>   it can be configured by setting the static property
>   AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier. ai.snapshot.version v2
>   ai.snapshot.id 6404b56bd53c4cd58857cc3c7bbb08f5 ai.snapshot.stampid
>   eastus-eit7xiflzk3gi System.InvalidOperationException: A claim of type
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier'
>   or
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider'
>   was not present on the provided ClaimsIdentity. To enable anti-forgery
>   token support with claims-based authentication, please verify that the
>   configured claims provider is providing both of these claims on the
>   ClaimsIdentity instances it generates. If the configured claims
>   provider instead uses a different claim type as a unique identifier,
>   it can be configured by setting the static property
>   AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier.
>
> at
>   System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.ClaimUidExtractor.GetUniqueIdentifierParameters(ClaimsIdentity
>   claimsIdentity, String uniqueClaimTypeIdentifier)
>
> at
>   System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.ClaimUidExtractor.ExtractClaimUid(IIdentity
>   identity)
>
> at
>   System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.TokenValidator.GenerateFormToken(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IIdentity identity, AntiForgeryToken cookieToken)
>
> at
>   System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.GetTokens(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AntiForgeryToken oldCookieToken, AntiForgeryToken&
>   newCookieToken, AntiForgeryToken& formToken)
>
> at
>   System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.GetFormInputElement(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext)
>
> at System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.GetHtml()
>
> at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.AntiForgeryToken()
>
> at ASP._Page_Views_JobTracking_Edit_cshtml.Execute() in
>   D:\home\site\wwwroot\Views\JobTracking\Edit.cshtml:line 17
>
> at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>
> at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>
> at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>
> at
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
>
> at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext
>   context)
>
> at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
>
> at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
>
> at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
>
> at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__1(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)

Here's the RouteConfig code:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "JobTracking/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "JobTracking", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Home",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
         }
    }
```

Here's the code in the controller

```
// GET: JobTracking/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(Guid? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Job_Tracking job_Tracking = db.Job_Tracking.Find(id);
            if (job_Tracking == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(job_Tracking);
        }
```

Comment: "I get an error"... what's the error

Comment: "Error. An error occurred while processing your request.",

Comment: as a side note, you should really consider adding logging to the server side

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the same but I am using Live Metrics Stream to view errors

Comment: and can you post an example of a get request to this action that is failing. your comment states `JobTracking/Edit/5` where `5` is not a valid guid so that would fail

Comment: https://teamweb.azurewebsites.net/JobTracking/Edit/41ba2cca-3e6c-4920-9f2f-92f656ab4374

Comment: and is a 400 being returned from the server?

Comment: It's a 500 error. The Guid is set to table row ID.  The code works on the staging slot.

Comment: if it's a 500 then the guid is being serialized by your controller action properly and there is an error occuring elsewhere (we know this because if it wasn't serialized properly, it would be null and your controller action would return a `BadRequest` which is a 400). more robust error handling/logging would help you diagnose these faster in the future but theres a very high probability that it's occurring in the `db.Job_Tracking.Find(id);` call. This means that there's something going wrong with the data that you're querying

Comment: note that `.Find` will return `null` if there is no matching guid primary key in the db table (can you verify the guid you're passing actually exists in the db?) if null is being returned by `.Find`, its possible you arent checking for this in the view and an exception is occurring.

Comment: I have confirmed the guid passed in the url matches the one in the db. I have copied other guid's directly from the db and pasted them into the url and still get the 500 error.

Comment: is `db` null in your prod environment for some reason? you really need to surround that code with a try/catch and get the exact exception and stacktrace that is being thrown. could also use a tool like sql server profiler to watch for the query comes in that searches for a record with a pk matching that guid which might help you diagnose the issue. also make sure the prod id column is actually a primary key and not just a column with the same name as your model environment. not much we can do here besides guess without having the actual exception being thrown

Comment: I've updated the question with the exception. DB is not null in production.

Comment: the exception references line 17 in your view. please post at least the relevant part of your view code

Comment: Line 17:  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the AntiForgeryConfig to use the `NameIdentifier` as follows in  the `Application_Start` method of `Global.asax.cs`:

`AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;`

If you haven't specified a `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` then you'll likely receive the following error after that change:

> A claim of type
>   'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier'
>   was  not present on the provided ClaimsIdentity.

To fix this, you can either specify a `NameIdentifier` which would be the best practice as follows:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "username"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "user@email.com"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "someUserId"),
};

//await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(userId, new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "someUserId")); if you're using Identity's UserManager
```

or if you have different unique claim data available but not a userId, you can set the `UniqueClaimIdentifier` to something else as follows (less acceptable):

`AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.Email;`

or the option which I would **very** strongly encourage you to stay away from would be to remove the antiforgery token from your view. i.e: delete `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`

Comment: As you suggested, the issue was fixed when I added the below. If I had needed to add the NameIdentifier , where would I do that?  AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;

Comment: you could add it when after a user is successfully logged in. if you found this helpful, please upvote so other may find it more easily in the future

Comment: It looks like I need a couple more reputation points to upvote